# ANTLR: how to remove global backtracking

Tags: antlr3

I tried to reproduce in ANTLR one example from the dragon book:

```
grammar left_recursion_2;

        options {

language = java;

}

program :   'begin'
             stmt+
            'end'
            ;

stmt    :   unmatched_stmt
        |   matched_stmt
        ;

matched_stmt    : 'if' expr 'then' matched_stmt 'else' matched_stmt
                | other
                ;


unmatched_stmt  : 'if' expr 'then' stmt
                | 'if' expr 'then' matched_stmt 'else' unmatched_stmt
                ;


expr    :   'expression'
        ;

other   :   'other'
        ;
```

The problem is the error 211:

> [fatal] rule unmatched_stmt has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.

I could switch backtracking on, but I would like to know how to solve it without backtracking. I also don't see, how predicates would help here. I read this:

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar

but still have no idea.

How would you rewrite the grammar so that it works without backtracking?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: in the mean time I've got to the conclusion that it is not possible. Since LL(*) uses DFA to look ahead, there is no chance to determine which rule to apply: the "if-else" rule or the "if only" rule. But if somebody has a better idea how to deal with it than using backtracking or postprocessing the AST, please let me know.